# How to make a Notification Channel queueable?

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-notification

If I create a custom notification channel like here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications#custom-channels
I get a "Driver not supported" when I implement the `ShouldQueue`. What do I need to to, to make a custom Notification Channel queueable?

Comment: what are you using as a driver for queuing?

Comment: The default sync driver